# "[Errno 101] Network is unreachable" when trying to send email using Django

Tags: python, django, email, gmail

For some reason I am getting this error when trying to send an email (with gmail) using Django.

```
[Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

The weird part about this is that it only seems to happen when my web app is running on my server (bluehost). It works fine when locally.

Here are my email settings

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'FakePassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Any idea as to how I can fix this?

Comment: what do your smtp settings look like?

Comment: @myusuf3 added to the original post

Comment: Do you connect through a proxy?

Comment: For any cPanel users out there, contact support and they can open post 587 for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is likely to have to do with the port you are trying to send email from on the blue host machine.

They probably block ports like that for security reasons.

More info: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/500

Comment: I think this is the problem... Checking with their support now. Thanks

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Did you found a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, it turned out that Bluehost blocks the port that gmail required. I just ended up using bluehosts email service instead.