# Django Sending Email : SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

Tags: python, django, email

hello i want to sending email activation use django registration redux.

this is my setting.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 3
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'blahblah@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'blahpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

when i try with

> python manage.py shell
>
> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>
> send_mail('Test', 'This is a test', 'youremail@gmail.com', ['toemail@gmail.com'])

i am getting error like this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/apsijogja/djangogirls/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/home/apsijogja/djangogirls/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 286, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/apsijogja/djangogirls/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 92, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/home/apsijogja/djangogirls/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 50, in open
    self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 249, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 310, in connect
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 361, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: That's definitely the wrong port...Also, change your Gmail password, and avoid posting actual credentials in public Stack Overflow posts...

Comment: try changing email port to 587

Comment: possible duplicate of ["\[Errno 101\] Network is unreachable" when trying to send email using Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949492/errno-101-network-is-unreachable-when-trying-to-send-email-using-django)

Comment: i already change with port 587 but still error

Comment: @rnevius in that link i am not understand about blue host machine.

Comment: can you see i already update my question and show error like that. how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270782/how-to-send-an-email-with-python)

Comment: For those who are using a correct port but still ended up with this error. Switching the email backend back to `console` (`EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`), confirming that your email ends up in the console upon password reset, before switching back to `smtp` helped to resolve this.

Answer (score 25):

To use port 465, you need to call smtplib.SMTP_SSL().
Currently, it calls smtplib.SMTP() ..
so,change your PORT from **465** into **587** it

if you want use PORT 465,

your `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'`

```
EMAIL_PORT=465
```

and you need to install `django_smtp_ssl`

otherwise you can keep,

`EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'`

```
EMAIL_PORT=465
```

Comment: Update: Django >=1.7 includes support for SMTP with SSL/TLS; hence django-smtp-ssl is obsolete.
https://github.com/bancek/django-smtp-ssl

Answer (score 3):

For python3.0+

I found a workaround or maybe this is the solution , there is some issue in the django email package.

1)pip install sendgrid-django

2)Add these in the settings.py along with other email configurations

```
  EMAIL_BACKEND = 'sgbackend.SendGridBackend'
  SENDGRID_API_KEY = "YOUR SENDGRID API KEY"
  EMAIL_PORT = 465
```

3)Code sample to send mail(yours maybe different):

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
send_email = EmailMessage(
    subject=subject,
    body=body,
    from_email=from_email,
    to=to_email,
    reply_to=reply_to,
    headers=headers,

)
send_email.send(fail_silently=fail_silently)
```

You have to certainly make changes to the code as i was just showing a example.

For debugging purpose only-[sendgrid mail send using telnet](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/getting_started_smtp.html)

Answer (score 2):

Please look into this Link: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9575
and try sending via shell, it should work

Answer (score 2):

I was developing and testing on localhost with the Gmail SMTP server and ran into this error. I figured out this was because I was using the `EMAIL_PORT = 465` on a `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True` configuration.

`EMAIL_PORT = 465` is an SSL port configuration and is supposed to be used alongside the `EMAIL_USE_SSL = True` configuration and not on a `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True` configuration.

So anybody that will run into this issue in the future with same mistake as me should change that and everything should work fine. Below is what the full SMTP configuration looked like for me:

```
# Email server configuration
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' 
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your_gmail_account@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

Also note that using TLS with `EMAIL_PORT = 587` and `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True` didn't work for me on Gmail, so I had to switch to using SSL and it worked.

Comment: I was using 587/TLS for months and today it stopped working ... using 465/SSL solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case using `smtplib.SMTP_SSL()` solve this problem. You can try this.

Answer (score 1):

Like myself, if your deployed django app is on heroku and using https meaning you need port 465, you should not forget to add these same values below here to your heroku `Config Vars`. It threw 'connection unexpectedly closed' error untill i had to add this.

`# settings.py`

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')                   
                     # replace here with the long SendGrid API secret code 
                     # xyxyxyxyzzzyz on heroku's Config Vars
EMAIL_PORT =  465 
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

Without that, debugging on localhost or development sever will work (with port 587 under http) but not at deployment under port 465 with https

Answer (score 1):

I'm using AWS SES and was having the same problem.

Using port **587** worked for me. Settings were pretty much identical to @User0511

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I used my api for EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD.
Then I found my SMPT password by going to https://app.mailgun.com/app/sending/domains/
Clicked on my domain name
Then Selected on SMPT

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is raised because wrong SENDGRID credentials
here you have to use

> EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'

Comment: Same answer as Laenka-Oss's but with less content.