# Send email from server python

Tags: python, email, ssl, smtp, server

I am trying to send an email form my server with python, I asked my server provider what port to use for this and they said "choose SMTP Ports 465 (Secure SSL/TLS outgoing server) , 25 ( Non-SSL outgoing server)." Not sure what this exactly means but currently I am using 25, here is my code

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import smtplib

import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 25)

#Next, log in to the server
server.login("youremailusername", "password")

#Send the mail
msg = "\nHello!" # The /n separates the message from the headers
server.sendmail("you@gmail.com", "target@example.com", msg)
```

I filled in my username (which is my email address right) and password,a dn the target but it is not working, when I try to navigate to the url where my py script is, it just doesn't load. I have an internet connection cause I am loving other things, and go to other pages on my server. I have also tried running with cron jobs but that also doesn't work.

The permissions on the script are 0755, is there a problem with the script?

When i ran with cron jobs here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/spencerf/public_html/cgi-bin/send_email.py", line 6, in <module>
   server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 25)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
   (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
   self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
   return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 567, in create_connection
   raise error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

**EDIT**

here is updated error log with the port at 587

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/spencerf/public_html/cgi-bin/send_email.py", line 7, in <module>
   server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
   (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
   self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
   return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 567, in create_connection
   raise error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

**EDIT 2**

When I had `server = smtplib.SMTP('telnet smtp.gmail.com', 587)`

I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/spencerf/public_html/cgi-bin/send_email.py", line 8, in <module>
   server = smtplib.SMTP('telnet smtp.gmail.com', 587)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
   (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
   self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
   return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
   for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 1):

**BUG:**

First of all you are using gmail server not your company server to send mail .For gmail server the output port is `587`

**The code:**

`Due to security issues gmail blocks accessing mail via code or program`

But still you can use gmail to send mail  via code if you do the following things

What i have done in code :

1.Added a error object to get the error message

```
import smtplib    

try:

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

    #Next, log in to the server
    server.login("youremailusername", "password")

    #Send the mail
    msg = "\nHello!" # The /n separates the message from the headers
    server.sendmail("you@gmail.com", "target@example.com", msg)
    print "Successfully sent email"
except smtplib.SMTPException,error:
    print str(error)
    print "Error: unable to send email"
```

If u ran this code u would see a error message like this stating  that google is not allowing u to login via code

Things to change in gmail:

1.Login to gmail

2.Go to this link  https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

3.Click enable then retry the code

Hopes it help :)

But there are security threats if u enable it

**Updated**

```
import smtplib       
try:
    content = 'test'

    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login("ABC@gmail.com", "password")
    mail.sendmail("ABC@gmail.com", "recivermailaddress", content)
    mail.quit
    print "Successfully sent email"
except smtplib.SMTPException,error:
    print str(error)
```

Comment: great thanks, and for server.login("","") is this the username and password of my gmail account that will be sending the email? So lets say my account is example_account@gmail.com would that be my username?

Comment: and i include the @gamil.com just to clarify?

Comment: I used your same code and got the same error but instead of port 25, it says port 587

Comment: Will try and say if you want

Comment: sorry what will you try?

Comment: yes it is working with both using `@gmail.com` and without `@gmail.com`

Comment: okay I tried that, and changed the port to 587, but I still get `network is unreachable`

Comment: Could you run the updated answer and say what error it is showing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949492/errno-101-network-is-unreachable-when-trying-to-send-email-using-django see this SO

Comment: try this and see if it still blocks then your company is blocking the port `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`

Comment: are you say try this: `server = smtplib.SMTP('telnet smtp.gmail.com', 587)`, and you are saying the server provider could be blocking port 587?

Comment: and Im looking at this https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en and doesn't say port 465 is also good?

Comment: it is a command prompt command to test connection your company might have blocked 587 .By running telnet you can be sure if they have blocked it or not

Comment: My company said "choose SMTP Ports 465 (Secure SSL/TLS outgoing server) , 25 ( Non-SSL outgoing server)." and how do I run `telnet`? if 587 is not there can i not connect to gmail?

Comment: Did you try both of the ports you could try your company mail if gmail did not work

Answer (score -1):

In python, please download [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) (disclaimer: I'm the developer):

```
pip install yagmail
```

It is then simply a matter of:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP("you@gmail.com", "password")
yag.send("target@example.com", 'This is the subject', 'Hello!')
```

I guess it mostly just has to do with the fact that you gave a wrong port (smtp.gmail.com is not at 25).

On the github you can also see a common list of [errors](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail#errors).

Comment: i'm getting network unreachable from both (my code and yagmail)