# What do I use as SMTP

Tags: php, python, email, smtp, backend

I am trying to write a Python script to send an email from my server, now from my research the first thing I see is I have to set `server = smtplib.SMTP('server?', 25)` and were `server`? is Im not sure what to put I have seen `smtp.gmail.com` and I have seen `localhost`, Ideally I want send the email form my Gmail account so I think I want `smtp.gmail.com` but when I have that I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/jam/public_html/cgi-bin/email.py", line 6, in <module>
   server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 25)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
   (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
   self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
   return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 567, in create_connection
   raise error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

So what is supposed to go there?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: It's for you to know which server you should use. It depends on where your mail service is. That's all rather irrelevant since your error message is 'Network unreachable' which suggests you have a network configuration problem somewhere.

Comment: @HoboSapiens what do you mean a network configuration problem, is this something I should ask my service provider about

Comment: You'll get a 'Network Unreacahble' message when your computer is unable to determine a route to the address you're trying to reach. This might be for any of a dozen reasons. There are other questions on [so] on this topic. I suggest you Google for 'Python network is unreachable' and work through some of the solutions there. You might start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949492/errno-101-network-is-unreachable-when-trying-to-send-email-using-django

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUE:**

First of all you are using gmail server to send mail .For gmail server the output port is `587`

Comment: I contacted my server provider to see what port to use and they said this "choose SMTP Ports 465 (Secure SSL/TLS outgoing server) , 25 ( Non-SSL outgoing server)." Do I have to send the email form my server email?

Comment: @jamesbrown you are sending mail from gmail for which you have to use their output port .If you are going to send mail from your company you can use your company port and you have to change the  `smtp.gmail.com` to your company mail.com

Answer (score 0):

To send email from your Gmail account, you can use Gmail's SMTP server per this Google Administrator Help page: [Google Apps SMTP settings to send mail from a printer, scanner, or app](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)

The following configuration requirements are provided for SMTP via `smtp.gmail.com`.

- Port 465 (SSL required)
- Port 587 (TLS required)
- Dynamic IPs allowed

Answer (score -2):

In python, please download [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) (disclaimer: I'm the developer):

```
pip install yagmail
```

It is then simply a matter of:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP('me@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
yag.send('to@gmail.com', 'This is the subject', 'This is the body')
```

On the github you can also see a common list of [errors](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail#errors).