# How to fix Network is unreachable with django's send_mail?

Tags: python, django, 3g, 4g

Failed to send mail with django's `send_mail()` over a 3g data connection as I tether from my phone. It takes a while and fails with a `Network is unreachable error`,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/local_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/local_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 283, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/local_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 92, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/local_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 50, in open
    self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 311, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 286, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

On the other, sending mail on a `4g connection` is successful.
I have a poor knowledge with networks and thus i cannot understand the cause.
**EDIT**
Doing this via localhost.

Comment: Why would you run your server tethered from your phone? You need to run it on an actual hosting provider somewhere.

Comment: See this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949492/errno-101-network-is-unreachable-when-trying-to-send-email-using-django

Comment: Am doing this via local development, i use my phone for the data connection purposes, data is expensive over here.

Comment: Ok, but maybe this port is blocked.

Comment: The most probable reason is - the port you're trying to connect to, is not open.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're only using your phone when doing local development, maybe it is an option to not actually send the email, but just print it to the console.

To do that, put this in your settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

It is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#console-backend).

Comment: Although this is not the answer i am looking for, it is great work around to get work done. Will up vote as i wait for an answer that to the real problem.